# Link List box to Subforms

Tags: ms-access-2010

How do you link a list box to Subforms. So when data is selected in list box the Subforms are then dependant on the list box?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Link Child and Link Master Fields of the subform control.

```
Link Master Fields : MyListBox
Link Child Fields : MyFieldName
```

This would require that the bound field on the listbox matches MyFieldName.